# Why background image not applying

Tags: html, css

The background image of the registration page is not displaying for some reason this is the html in web form with master page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeProject.Registration" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <link href="LogInStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="container">

            <h1 class="sign_up">Sign Up</h1>   
            <hr  style="border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;margin-bottom:30px;"/>

            <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="tzz" id="tzzjs" /> <!-- תעודת זהות -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fn" required="required"/>  <!-- שם פרטי -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="ln" required="required"/> <!-- שם משפחה -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required="required"/> <!-- אימייל -->
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required="required" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" /> <!-- סיסמא -->
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required="required"  /> <!-- חזרה על סיסמא -->
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" title="phone-number" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" required="required"/> <!-- טלפון -->

            <div style="height:20px;"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="subReg" value="Submit" /> <!-- ביצוע טופס -->

        </div>       
</asp:Content>
```

this is the css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
}

.bg {
    background-image: url("images/maxresdefault.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password] ,input[type=tel]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}


input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color:#fffdc0;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    color:black;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=tel]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline:none;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px;
}

form {
    width: 30%;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:670px;
    background-color:white;
    
}

.sign_up{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

when I apply the CSS to a normal HTML page the background picture display's but when I apply the CSS to the web form with master page the BG image doesn't display

Comment: Give `.bg` a `width` of `100%`

Comment: it dosent work:(

Comment: There is some other error, It is working fine even without the `width: 100%;`. the URL may be wrong. See Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNWemEM?editors=1100

Comment: yep the URL is correct I think the problem is because of the webform

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the file path for your local image? How are your files structured? As you can see it works fine with a URL.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
}

.bg {
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/8d/63/af8d63a477078732b79ff9d9fc60873f.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password] ,input[type=tel]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}


input[type=submit] {
    width: 30%;
    background-color:#fffdc0;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    color:black;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus, input[type=tel]:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
    outline:none;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px;
}

form {
    width: 30%;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:670px;
    background-color:white;
    
}

.sign_up{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="SomeProject.Registration" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <link href="LogInStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="container">

            <h1 class="sign_up">Sign Up</h1>   
            <hr  style="border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;margin-bottom:30px;"/>

            <input type="text" placeholder="ID" name="tzz" id="tzzjs" /> <!-- תעודת זהות -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fn" required="required"/>  <!-- שם פרטי -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="ln" required="required"/> <!-- שם משפחה -->
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required="required"/> <!-- אימייל -->
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required="required" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" /> <!-- סיסמא -->
            <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required="required"  /> <!-- חזרה על סיסמא -->
            <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" title="phone-number" pattern="[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}" required="required"/> <!-- טלפון -->

            <div style="height:20px;"></div>
            <input type="submit" name="subReg" value="Submit" /> <!-- ביצוע טופס -->

        </div>       
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: yes the structure is fine i even tried it on a normal html page and it worked , i think the problem is something in the webform